# Javascript - Formatear un número en string local a number

Tags: javascript

¿Hay alguna forma de parsear "1.100" (1100 en España) a 1100?

Por supuesto, parseInt devuelve 1, no sabe que es un número en español.

```
Intl.NumberFormat("es-Es").format(number);
returns "1.1"
```

Podría hacer un par de funciones para cambiar el "#.###" por "#,###", es decir, todos los puntos por comas, pero me gustaría saber si ya existe algún método nativo más sencillo.

Answer (score 3):

La función `parseInt` no soporta separadores de miles, puedes considerar que simplemente parará al primer caracter que no sea un número.<sup>1</sup>

Lo que generalmente puedes hacer es eliminar los separadores de miles, por ejemplo con la función `replace`.

```js
function demostrar() {
  var sa = "1.100";
  var a = parseInt(sa) + "<br>"                      //tal como está
        +  parseInt(sa.replace('.', ',')) + "<br>"   //sustituyendo el separador de miles . por ,
        +  parseInt(sa.replace('.', '')) + "<br>";   //eliminando el separador de miles
  
  var b = parseInt("10.00") + "<br>";
  var c = parseInt("10.33") + "<br>";
  var d = parseInt("34 45 66") + "<br>";
  var e = parseInt("   60   ") + "<br>";
  var f = parseInt("40 años") + "<br>";
  var g = parseInt("Él tiene 40") + "<br>";

  var h = parseInt("10", 10)+ "<br>";
  var i = parseInt("010")+ "<br>";
  var j = parseInt("10", 8)+ "<br>";
  var k = parseInt("0x10")+ "<br>";
  var l = parseInt("10", 16)+ "<br>";

  var n = a + b + c + d + e + f + g + "<br>" + h + i + j + k +l;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
```

```html
<p>Haz clic en el botón para probar el código</p>

<button onclick="demostrar()">¡Probemos!</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

He dejado otros ejemplos, obtenidos de [`parseInt` en w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) porque me parecieron educativos.

Si te fijas en los primeros valores, solamente la eliminación del separador de miles da el resultado que esperas.

---

<sup>1</sup>En realidad es algo un poco más complejo, pues `parseInt` soporta espacios al inicio del número y números hexadecimales, que inician con `"0x"` y tienen dígitos como `A, B, C`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Podrías usar [Globalize](https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize)

> Una biblioteca de JavaScript para internacionalización y localización que aprovecha los datos oficiales de [Unicode CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/) JSON. La biblioteca funciona tanto para el navegador como en Node.js.

Puntualmente la función [.numberParser([options])](https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize/blob/master/doc/api/number/number-parser.md)

#### Ejemplo:

```js
$.when(
    $.getJSON('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/unicode-cldr/cldr-numbers-full/master/main/es/numbers.json'),
    $.getJSON('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/unicode-cldr/cldr-numbers-full/master/main/en/numbers.json'),
    $.getJSON('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/unicode-cldr/cldr-core/master/supplemental/likelySubtags.json')
  )
  .then(function() {
    // Formateamos las respuestas
    return [].slice.apply(arguments, [0]).map(function(result) {
      return result[0];
    });
  })
  .then(Globalize.load)
  .then(() => {
    var enParser = Globalize("en").numberParser(),
      esParser = Globalize("es").numberParser(),
      number = '1.100';

    console.log('EN: ', enParser(number));
    console.log('ES: ', esParser(number));
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cldrjs/0.5.1/cldr.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cldrjs/0.5.1/cldr/event.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/globalize/1.5.0/globalize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/globalize/1.5.0/globalize/number.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: He probado la libreria Globalize aunque la he descartado porque creo que es demasiado ambiciosa.

Es importar demasiado para una simple función, finalmente he decidido utilizar replace. Tengo que depurar el método pero seguramente subiré la función. 

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Usando el objeto [Int.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Intl/NumberFormat) podías hacer lo siguiente:

- Buscar el **separador decimal** para el `locale` del que se quiere obtener el número.
- Reemplazar **todo lo que sea distinto** de números, signo negativo y el separador decimal de dicho `locale`.
- Reemplazar el **separador decimal** de dicho `locale` por **punto**.
- Aplicar [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/parseFloat) a la cadena resultante.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
function numberParser(value, locale) {
  // Obtenemos un numero formateado para descubrir el separador decimal
  let number = Intl.NumberFormat(locale).format(.1),
    // Obtenemos el separador decimal
    decimalSep = number[1],
    // Creamos el patrón para dejar solo números, signo negativo y el sep. decimal
    pattern = new RegExp('[^\-0-9' + decimalSep + ']', 'g'),
    // Buscamos cuantos separadores decimales tiene
    matchs = value.match(new RegExp('['+decimalSep+']', 'g'));

  // [OPCIONAL] Validamos que si tiene separador decimal, no sea mas de uno
  if (matchs && matchs.length > 1) return NaN;

  // Limpiamos y reemplazamos el sep. decimal por punto
  number = value.replace(pattern, '').replace(decimalSep, '.');
  return parseFloat(number);
}

let number = '1.100';
console.log('EN: ', numberParser(number, 'en'));
console.log('ES: ', numberParser(number, 'es'));

number = '-1.000.100,20';
console.log('EN: ', numberParser(number, 'en'));
console.log('ES: ', numberParser(number, 'es'));
```